# 3 tables into one array

Tags: c#, database

Im trying to take 3 tables into one array.  THe stored procedure works. At the first add line it errors saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Any way to do this? Im not sure if im going about this completely wrong. Thanks ahead of time.

```
    public static ArrayList SearchContacts(string search)
    {
        Contacts C = new Contacts();
         ContactsAddress D= new ContactsAddress();
         ContactPhone E = new ContactPhone();
        ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
        SqlDataSource ds = Database.GetDataSource();
        ds.SelectCommand="_ContactSearch";
        ds.SelectCommandType=SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;

         ds.SelectParameters.Add("FirstName", DbType.String,C.FirstName.ToString());
         ds.SelectParameters.Add("LastName", DbType.String,C.LastName.ToString());
         ds.SelectParameters.Add("EmailAddress", DbType.String,C.EmailAddress.ToString());
         ds.SelectParameters.Add("PostalCode", DbType.String,D.PostalCode.ToString());
         ds.SelectParameters.Add("PhoneNumber", DbType.String,E.PhoneNumber.ToString());

         IEnumerator i = ds.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty).GetEnumerator();
        while (i.MoveNext())
        {
            DataRowView d = (DataRowView)i.Current;

            fillSearch(d, ref C,ref D, ref E);
            ret.Add(C);
            ret.Add(D);
            ret.Add(E);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Do we get to guess what the error is? Do we also get to guess why you accept virtually no answers that others have provided you?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the actual error that is occurring.

Comment: Where are any property values in the new Contacts C set? You create new one and then reference it's properties. I would expect them to be null.

Answer (score 0):

My  guess is that your `Contacts` constructor isn't setting a value for the `FirstName` field. So when you call `C.FirstName.ToString()`, it throws a null reference exception.